# Bast way to move file from server to server in PHP

Tags: php, download

I have sites where stored some xml files, and I want to download to our server, we don't have ftp connection, so we can download through http. I always used `file(url)` is there any better way to download files through php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can access them via http, `file()` (which reads the file into an array) and `file_get_contents()` (which reads content into a string) are perfectly fine provided that the wrappers are enabled.

Comment: Small caveat. You will be limited by php memory size limit doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Using CURL could also be a nice option:

```
// create a new CURL resource 
$ch = curl_init(); 

// set URL and other appropriate options 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.server.com/file.zip"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

set_time_limit(300); # 5 minutes for PHP 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300); # and also for CURL 

$outfile = fopen('/mysite/file.zip', 'wb'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $outfile); 

// grab file from URL 
curl_exec($ch); 
fclose($outfile); 

// close CURL resource, and free up system resources 
curl_close($ch);
```